Question about Chern-Simons forms
In a paper, it is claimed that "It is a well known fact from the theory of characteristic classes that a primitive for the difference of two representatives of $p_1$ is given by the corresponding Chern-Simons form:
$$ tr(F_1 \wedge F_2) - tr(F_2 \wedge F_2) = d\left( tr\left(F_1 + F_2) \wedge (A_1 - A_2)\right) - \frac{1}{3}tr\left((A_1 - A_2)^3\right)\right).$$"
Context: We have a manifold $M$ with dimension 4n. $P \rightarrow M$ is a principal $G$ bundle where $G$ is a compact Lie group. I think $p_1$ is the first Pontryagin class. Also, $A_1, A_2$ are connections on $P$ and $F_1,F_2$ are their corresponding curvature 2-forms. "$tr$" stands for the trace. Does anyone know of a reference for this well-known fact? There are statements which look similar in many textbooks, but none that I found were quite the same.

See, for example, pp. 128-129 of the second edition of Chern's Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory. This portion of the book is the paper "Geometry of Characteristic Classes," Proc.  13th Biennial Sem. Canadian Math. Congress (1972), 1–40.
